# Hookin' Images from phone storage with React-Hooks

Tags: react-native, mobile, react-hooks

The RNImage Picker says: 'Then later, if you want to display this image in your render() method:' But it's a default function. How can I display the image on screen?

```js
export default function Expenses(){

  const [ imageSource, setImageSource ] = useState(null);
  const [ data, setData ] = useState(null);

   uploadImage = async () => {
    ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
      console.log('Response = ', response);

      if (response.didCancel){
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (response.error){
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error)
      } else if (response.customButton){
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      } else {
        const source = { uri: response.uri };
        setImageSource({
          imageSource: source
        });
      }
    })
  };
```

> > I'm using Styled-components and Photo it's styled.Image.

```js
return (
  <Container>
    <Photo source={imageSource} />
    <ButtonTouch
      onPress={uploadImage}>
      <TextButton>Select Image</TextButton>
    </ButtonTouch>
  </Container>
  );
}
```

> And let me simplify for yall. I'm trying get this photo on my phone storage or take a photo, whatever and display this photo on screen. But I can't display that. Return nothing.